# VBA Find/FindNext

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to accomplish something and my lack of coding knowledge is slowing me and my project down.

I have three tables, source table, input table and the output table, like in the screenshot shown here:

[image: The three tables in excel, source, input and output]

What I want my code to do is cycle through the names in the input table and whenever the code finds its equal in the source table, then it will copy the NUM,NAME and PRICE into the output table, like this for the Name a:

[image]

It should skip the one ones, that are not in the source table, e and f, the result should look like this:

[image]

This is what I came up with so far

```
Sub TEST_2_2()

Dim LastInputRow As Integer 'Count the number of rows in my input table
LastInputRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastSourceRow As Integer ' count the the number of rows in my source table
LastSourceRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer 'declare a variable for monitoring on which row in my input table Iam
Dim MatString As String 'String we are searching for
Dim MatRange As Range 'The range we are currently in

For i = 2 To LastInputRow
    MatString = Range("F" & i).Value
    Set MatRange = Range("B1:B" & LastSourceRow).Find(What:=MatString)
    If Not MatRange Is Nothing Then
        'Can´t figure this out
    Else
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Data used is only to show my problem, in reality I'm working with much larger tables, but the gist is the same.

Any help on how I should solve it are welcome, as I said I'm not very experienced, so any tips will come in handy, thank you!

Comment: Easier to loop over the source table and run a Match against the input table, then copy if there's a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
ar = Application.Transpose(Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)))
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ar, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
Destination:=Range("i1")
Cells.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Work like a charm, never thought of filtering something and jumped straight to for loops, thank you, for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your output would be your Source Table filtered by the names in your Input table.

*Note: When you wrote `table`, I assumed it was an Excel table.  If not, you can change the ListObject range references to regular references)

Here is VBA code that will accomplish that:

```
Option Explicit
Sub outputTable()
    Dim LOS As ListObjects, WS As Worksheet
    Dim loSource As ListObject, loInput As ListObject, loOutput As ListObject
    Dim rFilteredData As Range, vFilter As Variant
    Dim v, w
    
Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet9") 'or whatever

Set LOS = WS.ListObjects
Set loSource = LOS("tblSource")
Set loInput = LOS("tblInput")

'get filtering values
'empirically it seems that entries in the filtering values array that do not 
'  exist in the table to be filtered are ignored.
'if this is not the case, some additional code may be needed
v = loInput.ListColumns("NAME").DataBodyRange

'if might have greater than 65,535 entries then
'  transpose using a loop
v = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)

loSource.Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        v, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        
Set rFilteredData = loSource.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

WS.Range("M:O").Clear
rFilteredData.Copy WS.Range("M1")

loSource.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

[image]

You can do the same thing with `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010+) by doing an `innerJoin` on the two tables:

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSource"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInput"]}[Content],
    output = Table.NestedJoin(Source,"NAME", Source2,"NAME","Output",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(output,{"Output"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"NUM", Int64.Type}, {"NAME", type text}, {"PRICE", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```